# The input and label size difference when training Auto Encoder model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to build an auto encoder model in python using tensorflow.

My input data is a numpy array (sp_pics) with shape=(419,128,128). I'm trying to use a CNN algorithm to do the auto encoder. This is my code:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(128, 128, 1))

# Encoder
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# Decoder
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

# Define Auto Encoder Model
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Train the Autoencoder
data_input = np.expand_dims(sp_pics, axis=-1)
autoencoder.fit(data_input, data_input, epochs=50, batch_size=32)

encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(sp_pics[0,:,:])

print(encoded_imgs.shape[1])
```

And I got this error when running autoencoder.fit()

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((1, 124, 124, 1) vs (1, 128, 128, 1)).
```

I don't now how I ended up with number "124".
Can anyone help me to fix this bug! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe you should have `padding=same` in all conv layers.

Comment: OMG, I'm indeed missing one "padding=same". Thank you so much for the help!!!!